# How can I restructure my loop to paginate faster right now it takes too long?

Tags: node.js, loops, pagination, github-api, fine-tuning

Per_page limit is 100 & I needed the function to be able to find results for any date range. So I added a do while loop and this is what I ended up with:

```
async function foo(repoOwner, repository, startingDate, endingDate){
    const listOfUserObjects = [];
    let pages, page = 1;
    do{
        await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url : `https://api.github.com/repos/${repoOwner}/${repository}/pulls?state=all&per_page=100&page=${page}`,
        }).then(response => {
            const users = response.data, startAt = new Date(startingDate), endAt = new Date(endingDate.valueOf());
            endAt.setDate(endAt.getDate() + 1);
            if(page === 1) pages = (Math.floor((users[0].number)/100))/2, console.log("collecting data, please wait...");
            for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                const createdDate = new Date(users[i].created_at), updatedDate = new Date(users[i].updated_at), closedDate = new Date(users[i].closed_at), mergedDate = new Date(users[i].merged_at);
                if(((createdDate || updatedDate || closedDate || mergedDate) >= startAt) && ((createdDate || updatedDate || closedDate || mergedDate) <= endAt)) {
                    const userObj = {};
                    userObj.id = users[i].id;
                    userObj.user = users[i].user.login;
                    userObj.title = users[i].title;
                    userObj.state = users[i].state;
                    userObj.created_at = users[i].created_at.slice(0,10);
                    listOfUserObjects.push(userObj);
                } else {
                    continue;
                };
            }
            page++
        }).catch(error => {
            throw error.response.status === 404 ? Error("Error 404 User or Repo Not Found") : Error(error);
        });
    } while(page < pages);
    console.log(listOfUserObjects);
}
```

- For paging through the data I added a do while loop. I expected it to loop through all the pages and retrieve the relevant data.
- The code works, but the do while loop is too slow and it loops through all the pages; instead I would prefer it to stop when the data from the desired date range has been retrieved.

This takes ages to retrieve data. Is there a more efficient way to do this?